# Which Ubuntu ver to run from DVD for 32 bit old PC?

Tags: 32-bit

Need urgently to run Ubuntu from DVD on an old 32-bit PC with a major Windows failure to save my files and get them to a new and safe system ASAP.

Got the 64 bit by mistake and no matter how much I checked I seem not to be able to figure which version I need to download - again, the PC is OLD, has a DVD-drive and is 32 bit.

Thank you ever so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you check here: *32-bit PC (i386) desktop image*

http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/